# pandas.DataFrame.drop dropped wrong label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, radar-chart

I'm using the code from https://python-graph-gallery.com/391-radar-chart-with-several-individuals/ and after I change some label of it, it is not working anymore.
I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'var1': [38, 1.5, 30, 4],
    'var2': [29, 10, 9, 34],
    'var3': [8, 39, 23, 24],
    'var4': [7, 31, 33, 14],
    'var5': [28, 15, 32, 14]
})

values = df.loc[0].drop('group').values.flatten().tolist()
values += values[:1]

values = df.loc[1].drop('group').values.flatten().tolist()
values += values[:1]

values = df.loc[2].drop('group').values.flatten().tolist()
values += values[:1]
```

It is just the same code from the website, and the radar graph is dropping `group` correctly. [image: correct radar graph]

But, if I change `var1` to `a` or anything else, it will not drop `group` correctly.[image: Incorrect radar]

I have tried all the way that I can try but it still didn't solve the issue. Whenever the name of `var2` changed, it is not dropping `group`. Please help me to solve it or tell me where is wrong, thanks!

Full Code:

```
# Libraries
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from math import pi

# Set data
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'var1': [38, 1.5, 30, 4],
    'var2': [29, 10, 9, 34],
    'var3': [8, 39, 23, 24], # if you change var3 to asdfs(some random thing), the issue will exist
    'var4': [7, 31, 33, 14],
    'var5': [28, 15, 32, 14]
})

categories = list(df)[1:]
N = len(categories)

angles = [n / float(N) * 2 * pi for n in range(N)]
angles += angles[:1]

ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

ax.set_theta_offset(pi / 2)
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)

plt.xticks(angles[:-1], categories)

# Draw ylabels
ax.set_rlabel_position(0)
plt.yticks([10, 20, 30], ["10", "20", "30"], color="grey", size=7)
plt.ylim(0, 40)

values = df.loc[0].drop('group').values.flatten().tolist()
values += values[:1]
ax.plot(angles, values, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="group A")
ax.fill(angles, values, 'b', alpha=0.1)

values = df.loc[1].drop('group').values.flatten().tolist()
values += values[:1]
ax.plot(angles, values, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="group B")
ax.fill(angles, values, 'r', alpha=0.1)

values = df.loc[1].drop('group').values.flatten().tolist()
values += values[:1]
ax.plot(angles, values, linewidth=1, linestyle='solid', label="group C")
ax.fill(angles, values, 'r', alpha=0.1)

plt.legend(loc='upper right', bbox_to_anchor=(0.1, 0.1))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  Would you please `print(values)` and post that in your question?

Comment: @JohnZwinck Full code posted, please check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that while you drop the correct *values*, you do not always drop the correct *names*.  The problem is in the first few lines:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'group': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    'var1': [38, 1.5, 30, 4],
    # ...
})

categories = list(df)[1:]
```

You construct the DataFrame from a dict.  And dicts do not retain the order you write them in, as you have assumed.  So `list(df)[1:]` may contain any arbitrary ordering of the column names from `df`, with one (arbitrary) name removed.

An easy fix is:

```
categories = df.columns.drop('group').tolist()
```

But note this may still leave you with a plot whose categories move around seemingly at random.  To control the order, here is one solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items([
    ('group', ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']),
    ('var1', [38, 1.5, 30, 4]),
    # ...
])
```

By using a list instead of a dict, the ordering will be preserved, and `list(df)[1:]` will always exclude `group`.

Comment: This is a great example of horrendous sample codes on the internet. ( I mean the example on python-graph-gallery.com , not this response!)

Comment: @RobertAltena: That's true.  Also very bad is how the original code converts all the data to lists before plotting, ensuring that when the data becomes larger, the program will become slow.  It basically doesn't need Pandas at all, since it only really operates on lists.

Comment: @JohnZwinck I'm with you. Since I am a new Python learner, Pandas here actually massed me up really hard, I thought it will be much easier if I just plot the data but since I have no idea how to do a 2+ radar graph, I gotta use the example from the website. Also, it is kind of hard to understand how come the 5 labels and the 5 data related. It is not a human logic that the label and the data are not corresponding.

Comment: @YINGFENG: It would be a good exercise to refactor the program to use a more sane structure, including plotting data from Pandas Series rather than Python lists.